# Is there a way of getting full name of background jobs/ processes?

Tags: bash, jobs

```
jobs -l
```

This lists the jobs, but my job names are long and identical and this leads to a confusion as to which one them completed. 
Eg: if my jobs are:

```
aaaaaabbbbbbccccc...............123
aaaaaabbbbbbccccc...............125
aaaaaabbbbbbccccc...............126
```

What I see in the output of jobs is

```
[1]   Running         aaaaaabbbbbbccccc....
[2]   Running         aaaaaabbbbbbccccc....
[3]   Running         aaaaaabbbbbbccccc....
```

Comment: What version of bash are you using? I can't reproduce this, I see the full job names. Can you reproduce this without your `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt - it's a bit hairy there's probably many cleaner ways, but it does the trick:

```
$ jobs
[4]   Running                 ./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 10000 &
[5]-  Running                 ./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab 10000 &
[6]+  Running                 ./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac 10000 &
```

To do what you want:

```
$ jobs -l | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f 2 | xargs -L1 -I PID bash -c "cat /proc/PID/cmdline ; echo"
./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa10000
./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab10000
./aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac10000
```

Explanation:

`jobs -l` lists the jobs with PID

`tr -s " "` compresses multiple spaces into single

`cut -d"" -f 2` selects the second field - the PID

`xargs ...` runs one command per line, and the command it runs is...

`bash -c {...}` to start a new bash shell which will run...

`cat /proc/xxx/cmdline` to show the command line which origianally started the process

Hope that helps.

Comment: *jobs -l* is giving the truncated output and since your solution is piping the truncated output to perform other operations, I'm still getting the same output.    
In your case the process names are small and hence output looks fine,

Comment: It works for me.  It doesn't use the name from `jobs -l` -- it uses the PID, and looks up the command line used to start that process from /proc.  I've noticed that, for me, `jobs` also shows the whole command line.  Start a job. gets its PID (`jobs -l`) and look it up in `/proc/PID/cmdline` -- what does it say?